# GraphicsMagick Error: gm convert: profile matches sRGB but writing iCCP instead

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

When I try to convert a jpg image to a png, I get the following errors message occasionally. What does it mean?

```
> gm convert xxx.jpg png32:xxx.png
gm convert: profile matches sRGB but writing iCCP instead (xxx.png).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an error but a warning.

Your input file (xxx.jpg) contains an ICC profile that represents sRGB.  The png writer notices that, and issues a warning (because writing a 13-byte sRGB chunk is more efficient than writing a multi-kilobyte iCCP chunk).  These days, even the sRGB chunk is wasteful if your image is intended to be displayed by a browser, because browsers assume that pixels are in the sRGB colorspace anyhow, when there is no color information present in the PNG file.